# Get value from json in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

Below is `json` string i want `Label` key value from given `json` string

If you have any idea share me ....

```
 {"Response":{"MetaInfo":{"Timestamp":"2014-04-28T11:55:00.689+0000"},"View":    
 [{"_type":"SearchResultsViewType","ViewId":0,"Result":[{"Relevance":1.0,"Location":
 {"LocationType":"point","Name":"22.32963 73.24493","DisplayPosition":    
 {"Latitude":22.3296299,"Longitude":73.244923},"MapView":{"TopLeft":
 {"Latitude":22.3386231,"Longitude":73.2352007},"BottomRight":
 {"Latitude":22.3206367,"Longitude":73.2546453}},"Address":{"AdditionalData":[]}}},
 {"Relevance":1.0,"Distance":32.4,"MatchLevel":"street","MatchQuality":
 {"Country":1.0,"State":1.0,"County":1.0,"City":1.0,"District":1.0,"PostalCode":1.0},"Location":
 {"LocationId":"LINK_939680173_L","LocationType":"point","DisplayPosition":
 {"Latitude":22.3296022,"Longitude":73.2452373},"MapView":{"TopLeft":
 {"Latitude":22.33396,"Longitude":73.24433},"BottomRight":
 {"Latitude":22.3287,"Longitude":73.24571}},"Address":`****`{"Label":"Harini,`****` Vadodara 390022, India","Country":"IND","State":"GJ","County":"Vadodara","City":"Vadodara","District":"Harini","PostalCode":"390022","AdditionalData":[{"value":"India","key":"CountryName"},{"value":"Gujarat","key":"StateName"}]}}}]}]}}
```

Comment: Have you tried *anything* so far? Json.NET? DataContractJsonSerializer?

Answer (score 3):

download Newtonsoft's json DLL.

then you can use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject or JsonConvert.SerializeObject

UPDATE:
Here are instructions on installing it via nuget for Visual Studio

http://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/

Here is an example on how to use it.

```
string json = @"{
'Name': 'Bad Boys',
'ReleaseDate': '1995-4-7T00:00:00',
'Genres': [
  'Action',
  'Comedy'
  ]
}";

Movie m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json);

string name = m.Name;
```

For your case just create an object for your JSON string (for each value) and then when you call deserializeObject you can reference the Label by using MyObject.label